# How to handle messages in WinApi C++ wrapper

Tags: c++, winapi

I am making a Windows API C++ wrapper. The header file looks like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
const int NOID = -1;

class inst {
    struct impinst;  // pimpl idiom
    impinst *imp;

    friend class win;   // win needs to see the private members of inst
                        // (namely, the WNDCLASS)
public:
    inst(const char *, HINSTANCE, int=NOID,
         HICON=LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION));

    ~inst();
};
class win {
    struct impwidget;  // pimpl idiom
    impwidget *imp;
public:
    win(inst &, const char *, int=0, int=0, int=600, int=450);
    void show(int);
    WPARAM msgpump();

    ~win();
};

// These are the object oriented message classes
// handler will be implemented by user of the library
class msg {
public:
    virtual void handler();
};
class movemsg : public msg {
public:
    void handler();
};
class sizemsg : public msg {
public:
    void handler();
};
```

The implementation (cpp) file:

```
#include "winlib.h"
struct inst::impinst {
    WNDCLASS wc;
    static LRESULT CALLBACK winproc(HWND hwnd, UINT wm, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
    {
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, wm, wp, lp);
    }
    impinst(const char *classname, HINSTANCE hInst, int menuid, HICON hi)
    {
        this->wc.style = 0;
        this->wc.lpfnWndProc = this->winproc;
        this->wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
        this->wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
        this->wc.hInstance = hInst;
        this->wc.hIcon = hi;
        this->wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        this->wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
        this->wc.lpszMenuName = (menuid == NOID) ?
                                NULL : MAKEINTRESOURCE(menuid);
        this->wc.lpszClassName = classname;

        if (!RegisterClass(&this->wc))
            throw "Could not construct window instance";
    }
};
inst::inst(const char *classname, HINSTANCE hInst, int menuid, HICON hi)
{
    this->imp = new impinst(classname, hInst, menuid, hi);
}
inst::~inst()
{
    delete this->imp;
}


struct win::impwidget {
    HWND hwnd;

    impwidget(inst &i, const char *text, int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        this->hwnd = CreateWindow(i.imp->wc.lpszClassName, text,
                                  WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, x, y, width, height,
                                  NULL, NULL, i.imp->wc.hInstance, NULL);
        if (this->hwnd == NULL)
            throw "Could not create window";
    }
};
win::win(inst &i, const char *text, int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    this->imp = new impwidget(i, text, x, y, width, height);
}
void win::show(int cmdshow)
{
    ShowWindow(this->imp->hwnd, cmdshow);
    UpdateWindow(this->imp->hwnd);
}
WPARAM win::msgpump()
{
    MSG msg;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
win::~win()
{
    delete this->imp;
}
```

I have a problem though: How can I pass all the message handler functions to my `inst` class, so they can be implemented in the `winproc` function? Right now, it is empty (just calls `DefWindowProc`), but I need it to somehow get all the user-provided implementations for the `handler` function and pass them to the `winproc` for handling. How could I do this? Do I need to pass a pointer to the `msg` class?

Edit:

My question is different, because my question asks *what* to pass to the `lpParam` argument of `CreateWindow`, not *how* like in the other question.

Comment: Google "wm_nccreate setwindowlongptr" to find code that shows you how to do this.  First hit is good.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object oriented c++ win32?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380294/object-oriented-c-win32)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing data through to a `winproc` callback is somewhat roundabout, but if you notice the documentation for `CreateWindow`, there's an `lpParam`parameter  which you can use to pass data through to a `WM_CREATE` or `WM_NCCREATE` event.

So you can do something like this:

```
MyData* my_data = ...;
this->hwnd = CreateWindow(i.imp->wc.lpszClassName, text,
                          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, x, y, width, height,
                          NULL, NULL, i.imp->wc.hInstance,
                          my_data /* passed to WM_NCCREATE: */);
```

Then in your `winproc`, when you receive a `WM_NCCREATE` message, we can associate that to the window handle using `SetWindowLongPtr`, like so:

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK winproc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (message == WM_NCCREATE)
    {
        MyData* my_data = (MyData*)(LPCREATESTRUCT(lParam)->lpCreateParams);
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)my_data);
    }
    ...
}
```

For the other events, you can then retrieve that data using:

```
LONG_PTR lpUserData = GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
if (lpUserData)
{
     MyData* my_data = (MyData*)(lpUserData);
     // do stuff with `my_data`
}
```

It's pretty roundabout so it's handy to wrap it and possibly make your own kind of `winproc` method on top of the callback to which you pass `my_data` (or `my_data` can be a pointer to a class and you can just call a method through that). Also make sure the pointee of `my_data` isn't destroyed before the window itself is destroyed.

This roundabout nature is needed because we have to first make sure the window is created successfully before we call `SetWindowLongPtr`. The most immediate place to do that is in the `WM_NCCREATE` event where we pass over the data through `CreateWindow`. Then we can retrieve that data and call `SetWindowLongPtr`, and access it through `GetWindowLongPtr` in subsequent events.

Comment: But what should I pass to the `lpParam` argument to `CreateWindow` in my case? I need to be able to call the `handler` function for every class that derives from `msg`. So would I pass a pointer to `msg`?

Comment: Basically whatever you need -- you have to squeeze it through a pointer. For example, you might pass in some aggregate structure or class which has everything you need available. Maybe you could store a list of base pointers to `msg` which stores all these msg instances through which you can call this `handler` method.

Comment: But first step is typically figuring out a way to pass data over to your `winproc` without just using a bunch of global variables. The above covers that part.

Comment: Are you trying to wrap it to kind of your own event handler system, like if you receive a `WM_SIZE` size event, call an instance of your `size_msg` handler? If so, it might be handy to keep a map of some sort which, say, maps WM_SIZE to an instance of `size_msg`. The data you pass through `lpParam` and associate persistently to the window through `SetWindowLongPtr` can contain that map (or possibly some kind of factory if you generate those instances on the fly).

Comment: Yes @Ike that is what I'm trying to do. Thanks for the suggestion. Should I use a lookup table to implement the map of windows messages to the class?

Comment: A LUT might be suitable or maybe `std::map`. Latter would be easier since you don't have to think much about how to map the keys in some kind of contiguous fashion.

Comment: Or you can just have a big class storing like `size_msg`, `move_msg`, etc. The inheritance might not help that much here since, for `winproc`, if you want to fetch the values passed to each event (`lParam`, `wParam`), you typically need branching and handle each event separately (have to handle `WM_PAINT` separately from `WM_MOVE` and `WM_SIZE` and so forth). It's hard to generalize that code without making `winproc` into a huge switch statement. So it might be easier to just have a switch case for `WM_SIZE`, then call like `my_data.size_msg.handle()` in there. `winprocs` tend to be...

Comment: ... kind of ugly monolithic functions with lots of branching because of the boatload of events to handle separately with separate parameters used for each.

Comment: Though if you want a light wrapper, you could, say, make `msg::handle` accept the `lParam` and `wParam` parameters passed to `winproc` and send them over to your individual handler types. Then you can just use a general kind of approach where you don't have to handle each and every winproc event separately -- just grab the appropriate msg handler from the map based on the `wm` and call it with the same parameters.

Comment: Could you save `my_data` as a static variable in the window procedure, so that other messages could access it, instead of having to use `SetWindowLong` and `GetWindowLong`?

Comment: @stackptr You can use a file-scope static variable, e.g. Typically it needs to be stored outside of winproc because we generally need to initialize it somewhere outside of it (ex: when creating the window). That can be simpler but the downside is that it only works if you have a single window using the same winproc. The benefit of using these functions instead to *associate* data to a window is the ability to be able to create multiple instances of it without writing a separate winproc for each window, e.g.

Comment: @stackptr ... each window, then, can have different data (its own instance data) associated to it.