# How to use WndProc as a class function

Tags: c++, c, class, winapi

I'm trying to create a class that includes the WndProc, but I'm getting an error :

`Error  2   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'LRESULT (__stdcall Client::* )(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM)' to 'WNDPROC'`

I searched the web for it, and seen that you need to make the WndProc static, but then, it compiles and everything is great, though if I want to change something, it doesnt let me :

`Error  3   error C2352: 'Client::CreateMen' : illegal call of non-static member function`

(CreateMen is a function in the class that creates the menu, using HMENU and such).

this is my function title:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

What can I do? I'm really confused...

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: First parameter in class functions is 'this' pointer.

Comment: You need to make the `WndProc` static, and save a pointer to your class somewhere you can access it (e.g. via a window property using `SetProp`/`GetProp`).

Comment: Remy's answer below looks correct. However, you may be re-inventing something that already exists. Check out CWindow and CWindowImpl template classes. I wrote up answer here a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3122743/104458

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A non-static class method has a hidden `this` parameter.  That is what prevents the method from being used as a WndProc (or any other API callback).  You must declare the class method as `static` to remove that `this` parameter.  But as you already noticed, you cannot access non-static members from a static method.  You need a pointer to the object in order to access them.

In the specific case of a WndProc callback, you can store the object pointer in the HWND itself (using either `SetWindowLongPtr(GWLP_USERDATA)` or `SetProp()`), then your static method can retrieve that object pointer from the `hWnd` parameter (using `GetWindowLongPtr(GWLP_USERDATA)` or `GetProp()`) and access non-static members using that object pointer as needed.

For example:

```
private:
    HWND m_Wnd;
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

```
LRESULT CALLBACK Client::WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    Client *pThis;

    if (msg == WM_NCCREATE)
    {
        pThis = static_cast<Client*>(reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCT*>(lParam)->lpCreateParams);

        SetLastError(0);
        if (!SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(pThis)))
        {
            if (GetLastError() != 0)
                return FALSE;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        pThis = reinterpret_cast<Client*>(GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA));
    }

    if (pThis)
    {
        // use pThis->member as needed...
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

```
m_Wnd = CreateWindowEx(..., this);
```

Comment: NOTE : put `WndProc` in public area not private because you can't use private member as callback input in functions :)

Comment: @PinnedObject `private` works just fine in my example, there is no need for it to be `public`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau can you provide your code to see how you use it? I get `E0265 function "Class::WndProc" is inaccessible` in vs2019, AFAIK it only works if window and window class be created in class functions itself not outside.

Comment: @PinnedObject Yes, the window class that is passed to `CreateWindowEx()` has to be registered inside of `Client` in order for a private `WndProc` to work. It doesn’t make much sense to pass `this` to `CreateWindowEx()` and register the window class outside of `Client`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, you're right but I don't mean using CreateWindowEx, You only register a WindowClass once not every time in each class and WindowClass needs WndProc and this is where issues comes up and there's two solution to this, making WndProc public or delegate it using a fake WndProc

Comment: @PinnedObject if you are using a per-`class` WndProc, it makes sense to register it in the same `class` that uses it. Then `private` works fine. If you register outside of the `class` then of course the WndProc will have to be made accessible to outside code, via `public` or `friend`, etc.

Comment: pThis returns nullptr...

Comment: @IOviSpot when used properly, it will only be `nullptr` until `WM_NCCREATE` is received (it is not the first message received) and then afterwards it should not be `nullptr` anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot use a class function as a wndproc because as the compiler tries to tell you the calling convention differs, even though the two functions have the same signature, a class function expects the this pointer to be passed to it. On 64 bit builds it will expect it to be in the RCX/ECX registry while on 32 bit builds it will expect the this pointer to be the last argument pushed on the stack. The window code won't do that when calling your WndProc essentially turning this into a function call on a garbage pointer.

What you **can** do is make a static method that does something like the following:

```
LRESULT Client::CreateMen(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    // The OS makes sure GWLP_USERDATA is always 0 before being initialized by the application
    Client* client = (Client*)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA);

    if(msg == WM_INIT)
    {
        client = new Client();
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, client);
    }

    if(msg == WM_DESTROY)
    {
        client = (Client*)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, client);
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, NULL);
        delete client;
        client = NULL;
    }

    if(client)
    {
        // Do stuff with the client instance
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}
```

I haven't tested this, so it might have some bugs, but let me know if you have any problems with it and I'll refine it if need be.

Comment: Why have a `Client` object (that is having CreateMen()` called on it) create a second `Client` object?  You can pass the original `Client` object to `CreateWindow/Ex()` directly and then have the WndProc call `SetWindowLong()` while the window is being created.  That way, `GWL_USERDATA` is ready for subsequent messages, and you don't need to use a custom INIT message.

Comment: The this pointer doesn't come through that register for a stdcall function

Comment: @RemyLebeau CreateMen is not called on a Client object, it's the implementation for the static window procedure. I thought it was better to keep the object inside the window procedure so external code doesn't touch it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for the correction, I've spent more time debugging 64 bit code than 32, so I was under the impression that the same convention of passing arguments in registers whenever possible applied, I'm going to correct that in my post, thanks.