# Using wndproc as a member function of a class

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, member, wndproc

I've been following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369256/how-to-use-wndproc-as-a-class-function) thread for how to use the wndproc function as a member function but I keep getting read access violations (it won't tell me the exact line in my program though, but it's at line 120 of xmemory0 `const uintptr_t _Ptr_container = _Ptr_user[-1];` and it says `Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation. _Ptr_user was 0x7.` I'm probably doing something funky that I shouldn't be doing. Does anyone see anything evident?

Code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK wndproc::WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg,
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    wndproc* pThis; //wndproc is the class name
    bool checked = true;

    HWND text, button, selection1, selection2;
    //hwnd is parent window

    switch (msg) {

    case WM_CREATE: {
        pThis = static_cast<wndproc*>(reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCT*>(lParam)->lpCreateParams);
        SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<::LONG_PTR>(pThis));
        text = CreateWindow("STATIC", "Please select options from below:", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 20, 20, 300, 25, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        button = CreateWindow("BUTTON", "Submit", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER, 500, 500, 80, 25, hwnd, (HMENU)0, NULL, NULL);
        selection1 = CreateWindow("button", "Scan?", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_CHECKBOX | WS_OVERLAPPED, 500, 460, 350, 20, hwnd, (HMENU)1001, NULL, NULL);
        CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1001, BST_CHECKED);
        LPCREATESTRUCT lpcs = reinterpret_cast<LPCREATESTRUCT>(lParam);
        vector<string> *strings = reinterpret_cast<vector<string>*>(lpcs->lpCreateParams);
        int j = 40;

        pThis->checkVectorSize = strings->size();
        for (int i = 1; i != strings->size() + 1; i++)
        {
            CreateWindowA("button", (*strings)[i - 1].c_str(),
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_CHECKBOX | WS_OVERLAPPED,
                20, j, 185, 35, hwnd, (HMENU)i,
                NULL, NULL);
            CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 0, BST_UNCHECKED);

            j = j + 30;
        }
        //SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<::LONG_PTR>(strings));

        break;
    }
    case WM_COMMAND: {
        pThis = reinterpret_cast<wndproc*>(GetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA));
        int i = wParam;
        if (i == 0) //LOWORD(wParam)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j != pThis->checkVectorSize; j++)
            {
                if (IsDlgButtonChecked(hwnd, j + 1) == true)
                {
                    pThis->check.push_back(j);
                }
            }
            if (IsDlgButtonChecked(hwnd, 1001) == true)
            {
                pThis->scan = true;
            }
            else
            {
                pThis->scan = false;
            }
            PostMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
            break;
        }
        checked = IsDlgButtonChecked(hwnd, i);
        if (checked) {

            CheckDlgButton(hwnd, i, BST_UNCHECKED);
        }
        else {
            CheckDlgButton(hwnd, i, BST_CHECKED);
        }
        break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY: {

        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    }
    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

EDIT: Wrapper function:

```
void wndproc::select(vector<string>& return)
{
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    WNDCLASSW wc = { 0 };
    MSG  msg;

    wc.lpszClassName = L"Selection1";
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 255));
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.style = CS_DBLCLKS;

    RegisterClassW(&wc);
    CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L"Selection",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE | WS_SYSMENU,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 0, hInstance, &return);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: `lpcs->lpCreateParams` point to what ? to `pThis` as you use in begin in `WM_CREATE` or to `vector<string> *strings` ?

Comment: Please show the declaration of WndProc (as given in the header file/class declaration). Is it a `static` function? Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: @WernerHenze It is a static function: `static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);`

Comment: @RbMm To both? I'm not really sure, I thought it might be a problem that I used that twice

Comment: as notice raymond chen and i - first you use `lpcs->lpCreateParams` as pointer to `wndproc* pThis;` and then you interpret the same pointer as `vector<string> *strings`. how minimum one cast is wrong

Comment: so almost 100% this line `vector<string> *strings = reinterpret_cast<vector<string>*>(lpcs->lpCreateParams);` is your direct bug

Comment: @RbMm I agree, I'm trying to figure out how to go about the problem. Right now I'm trying the solution posted by Someprogrammerdude

Comment: `wndproc::select` is fake code. If you need help, don't post fake code.

Comment: @IInspectable Fake code? The rest of the function was doing simple calculations on values gathered by `wndproc::WndProc`, not relevant at all to the problem.

Comment: Yes, fake code. Neither I nor your compiler knows, what `&ret` is.

Comment: I changed it to `return` to make things more clear. I forgot to change it at that line

Comment: Even more fake code, now. You cannot use a reserved keyword as a formal parameter. Stop posting fake code.

Comment: @IInspectable lol you're crazy man. Try the code out yourself. That's perfectly legal to do. I know the code works. It's not like I haven't been able to test it. I just want WndProc to be a member function.

Comment: If I'm saying, that code does not compile, that code [does not compile](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IIwiGUlt5izyJTgj). You are posting fake code, code you aren't seeing in front of yourself. If you need help, stop doing that. See [ask].

Comment: It's obviously not going to compile for you because you don't know the member variables (such as `bool scan`)

Comment: I'm referring to `wndproc::select`, which doesn't compile for *you* as well. It's fake code. Either show a [mcve], or have this closed off as off-topic.

Comment: You are passing the address of a string vector as the last parameter of `CreateWindowW`. This gets passed to your window procedure as the `lpcs->lpCreateParams`. But you cast it to `wndproc*` which is not what it is. Confusion quickly ensues. If you want to pass two things to your `WM_CREATE` handler, then pass a pointer to a struct.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you, that's an excellent idea. I created a struct with the two data pieces but createWindowW isn't accepting the struct as the last argument `no suitable conversion function from "x" to "LPVOID" exists` where "x" is the name of the struct.

Comment: *"pass a **pointer** to a struct"*.

Comment: There we go, thank you. Do I have to reinterpret the lParam as "x" where x is the name of the struct?

Comment: It sounds like you're struggling with more fundamental issues with C++. I would suggest that you hone your skills with simpler programs first.

Comment: @RaymondChen That's probably a good idea. I've been trying to learn things from the grassroots up over the past few weeks, I may have dived into this project a bit too soon. Since it's rather important that I get this finished up soon, I'm going to try to work out this problem first though and then continue reading/watching tutorials on youtube. Do you know the proper way to reinterpret the lParam as a struct so I can access the struct's variables? I tried `x data2 = static_cast<x*>(reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCT*>(lParam)->lpCreateParams);`

Answer (score 2):

Non-static member functions are *not* the same as a non-member function. Non-static member function needs an object to be called on, which non-member functions doesn't need.

If you don't use any other (non-static) member functions or member variables, you could make the function `static` and it should work.

---

Another possible solution, considering that you're passing "this" along to the function in other ways, is partially the same as the solution mentioned above, together with a second non-static member function.

Something like

```
class wndproc
{
    ...

    static LRESULT WndProcWrapper(...)
    {
        wndproc *pThis;

        // Set pThis...

        // Call *real* window procedure
        return pThis->WndProc(...);
    }

private:
    LRESULT WndProc(...)
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

Then make `wndproc::WndProcWrapper` the window procedure.

Comment: What would be the solution then? Get rid of the pThis? However, WndProc is declared as static: `static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);`

Comment: When I set my other function as static (not the WndProc function), I get a compiler error here `wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;` saying type LRESULT cannot be assigned to WNDPROC.

Comment: Check my edit up top, it shows the wrapper function I'm using. I'm not exactly sure how to make WndProcWrapper "the window procedure". Let me know if I shouldn't use my above function as the wrapper

Comment: @Colebacha2 First of all, the function you added is your creation and message loop, not a wrapper function. As for your problem, have youturned `wndproc::WndProc` into a `static` member function?

Comment: @Colebacha2 And please try to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and **Verifiable** Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us (but don't just copy-paste your whole code, make sure to not forget the **Minimal** part as well).

Comment: My apologies. As per your example, I removed the `static` from `wndproc::WndProc` and instead made the other function static. Would my wrapper function simply call my `select` function?

Comment: @Colebacha2 With my solution, you should do `wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProcWrapper;` in your `select` function (which is really badly named since it doesn't really select anything). And I suggest you take some time to study requirements analysis and design, as well as UI and event handling in general.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't set `wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProcWrapper;` because `LRESULT (*)() cannot be assigned to a type WNDPROC`. My `select` function actually does do some selecting but I didn't include that part to keep it minimal

Comment: @Colebacha2 You of course need a *proper* declaration with the correct arguments! What I shown are just *excerpts* to convey the idea, not exact code that should be copy-pasted!

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not all that familiar with winapi.I really don't see anything wrong with the declaration `wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProcWrapper;` I probably won't be using winapi it after this. I'll just stick to Qt because it seems a lot simpler and more feature-filled.